# SqlBulkCopy Simulate Delay

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, ado.net

I want to bulk load data into a SQL 2008 table using SqlBulkCopy. I plan to load the data in parallel from multiple clients.

However i want to simulate a delay in loading the data so that i can check for locks in the database and check for concurrency issues. I normally use Thread.Sleep() to simulate a long running process, but i'm not sure if its working with SQLBulkCopy.

```
 using (SqlBulkCopy s = new SqlBulkCopy(connectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock))
{


s.DestinationTableName = "HoldTable";    
s.WriteToServer(dataTable);    
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000000);    
s.Close();
}
```

Comment: It is not simulating a delay, it is a delay.  What are you trying to do, make the process take 15 minutes longer than necessary?

Comment: @Ben obviously i'm not going to have System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000000) in actual implementation, its just there for testing to "simulate" the bulkimport taking really long

Answer (score 0):

By default, `SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer` runs outside a transaction.  That means it will release any locks before the `WriteToServer` function returns.  There won't be any database locks during your `Sleep`.

You can use a transaction by specifying the [third parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) to `SqlBulkCopy`'s constructor.  See [this MSDN article for examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tchktcdk%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

A transaction keeps its locks until you commit it.  So if you put the `Sleep` just before the commit, you should have a useful simulation.

Comment: that doesn't seem to work WriteToServer(dataTable) seems to open and commit the transaction in one call, i can not hook the thread.sleep in between

Comment: Have a look at the [third example, "Using Existing Transactions"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tchktcdk(v=vs.80).aspx).  You can run `WriteToServer` as part of a C# transaction.